How to get a indicator on firefox when moving tabs
I am looking for a way to get an indicator to show up when moving tabs in Firefox (and variants).
This is broken with Firefox multitab using chrome CSS.

This feature seems to be present in one of its variants Cachy.

Screencapture of the blue key like indicator (uncertain of the proper terminology).

Both are version 126.0.
I'm open to ideas on how else to achieve this if this is not the correct way.
